# Adding text to an output in HTML JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need the output of this site: https://tew-hop-2-1.glitch.me/

to look like this: [image]

```
var celsius = "degrees, Celsius";


function convert() {

var degF= document.getElementById("fValue").value
var degC= (degF - 32) * (5 / 9);
document.getElementById("cValue").innerHTML = degC.toFixed(1); 
} 
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", convert, false);
```

this is what i have for the code but I cannot figure out how to change it to have that output.

Comment: You should include your HTML and CSS so we can better debug.

Comment: I get the same result as the included photo ! @ScottMarcus me either.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `convert` function. You're setting `innerHTML` to be the value of `degC`, not the degrees and your string. Try this instead.

```
var celsius = "degrees, Celsius";


function convert() {

    var degF= document.getElementById("fValue").value
    var degC= (degF - 32) * (5 / 9);
    document.getElementById("cValue").textContent = degC.toFixed(1) + celsius; 
 } 
 document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", convert, false);
```

Comment: And, how about not using `.innerHTML` at all unless your string actually contains HTML that needs to be parsed? Use `.textContent` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I didn't know it was better to use `.textContent` and have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I'm mostly a back-end/fullstack developer, and therefore avoid using innerHTML as much as possible, as a security measure to prevent any HTML or javascript injections. There is less risk of that in only-javascript, but figure always lean toward most secure way to do something. Which in this case also probably has minor performance benefits not invoking as much DOM parsing/updating code

Comment: @Thymine Actually, the performance benefits can be measurable.